# WP Instant search by restaurant

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm looking to build an extra search functionality much like the one that already exists on the main menu on the right (Next to "Neighbourhoods"). Except I want it to search by the restaurant only. How would I go about doing this? The current search function does not include the restaurant listings and I want an extra search function to search by restaurants only.

Is there a plugin that will allow me to do this as well?

Website link: [View here](http://www.mycitylife.ca/restaurants/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search a specific post type by adding a `post_type` input to your [search form](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-search-by-post_type?replies=5). This can be a select box, hidden field, etc. Assuming your custom post type is "restaurant" you could use the following to have your form only search that type.

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="restaurant" />
```

This can also be done programmatically using the [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter to add the `post_type` parameter to your `WP_Query`.

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'restaurant' ) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it's using a custom instant search from the theme developer. 

I'm sure yours works and I am glad you've pointed that out, I learned :)
I've figured it out with the current theme